# drowing a 1d lattice graph in python networkx

Tags: python, graph, networkx, lattice

I am tying to plot  1d lattice graph, but i face with below:

NetworkXPointlessConcept: the null graph has no paths, thus there is no averageshortest path length
what is the problem of this code?
thanks.

```
N = 1000
x = 0
for n in range(1, N, 10):
    lattice_1d_distance = list()
    d = 0
    lattice_1d = nx.grid_graph(range(1,n))
    
    d = nx.average_shortest_path_length(lattice_1d)
    lattice_1d_distance.append(d)
    x.append(n)
plt.plot(x, lattice_1d_distance)  
plt.show()
```

Comment: i have imported networkx as nx

Comment: Why ```range (1,n)``` ? If you create ```nx.grid_graph(range(1,1))``` it will be an empty graph with **zero nodes**, average_shortest_path_length is undefined in this case, of course, there will be an error.

Comment: what should i write instead of range()?

Comment: Are you generating  ```[1], [1,2], [1,2,3] ... [1,2,3...,n]``` as the dimension for the grid graphs and calculate average_shortest_path_length for each of these grid graphs?

Comment: i want to set my nodes number in range(1, N, 10)

Comment: Ok, if you use ```range(1,n)``` in ```nx.grid_graph()``` you are essentially asking the program to draw an n-2 dimensional grid_graph, you are **NOT setting the node numbers**, but you are setting the **dimension** of the grid graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to networkx documentation [`nx.grid_graph`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.generators.lattice.grid_graph.html?highlight=grid_graph#networkx.generators.lattice.grid_graph) the input is a list of dimensions for `nx.grid_graph`

**Example**

```
print(list(range(1,4)))
nx.draw(nx.grid_graph(list(range(1,4))) # this is a two dimensional graph, as there is only 3 entries AND ONE ENTRY = 1

[1, 2, 3]
```

[image]

```
print(list(range(1,5)))
nx.draw(nx.grid_graph([1,2,3,4])) # this is a 3 dimensional graph, as there is only 4 entries AND ONE ENTRY = 1

[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

[image]

Therefore, lets say if you want to 1. plot the **distance vs increment of number of dimensions for grid graphs** but with constant **size for each dimension**, or you want to 2. plot the **distance vs increment of size for each dimension for grid graphs** but with constant **number of dimensions**:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 10
x = []
lattice_1d_distance = []
for n in range(1, 10):
    d = 0
    lattice_1d = nx.grid_graph([2]*n) # plotting incrementing number of dimensions, but each dimension have same length.
    d = nx.average_shortest_path_length(lattice_1d)
    lattice_1d_distance.append(d)
    x.append(n)
plt.plot(x, lattice_1d_distance)  
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
N = 10
x = []
lattice_1d_distance = []
for n in range(1, 10):
    d = 0
    lattice_1d = nx.grid_graph([n,n]) # plotting 2 dimensional graphs, but each graph have incrementing length for each dimension.
    d = nx.average_shortest_path_length(lattice_1d)
    lattice_1d_distance.append(d)
    x.append(n)
plt.plot(x, lattice_1d_distance)  
plt.show()
```

[image]

Also, you need to pay attention to the declaration of list variables.

Comment: thanks for your complete and great answer:)